# Random number generator upto 2 decimal places using Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

How do I generate random numbers upto 2 decimal places? I am using random.rand but it goes upto 8 decimal places.

```
import numpy as np
Pe = np.random.rand(5,5)
```

The current output is

```
array([[0.53084542, 0.39162757, 0.08501123, 0.00391447, 0.83859363],
       [0.16194795, 0.06216611, 0.96712453, 0.01319061, 0.19207092],
       [0.90371594, 0.80225188, 0.87797408, 0.71086006, 0.2258896 ],
       [0.33869247, 0.16054   , 0.85156147, 0.25426089, 0.87377881],
       [0.79342404, 0.08150748, 0.62888488, 0.43499343, 0.98077841]])
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

generate floats and [`round`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.round.html) to the wanted decimal places:

```
D = 2
np.random.rand(5,5).round(D)
```

or use integers and divide:

```
D = 2
np.random.randint(10**D, size=(5,5))/10**D
```

example output:

```
array([[0.21, 0.6 , 0.75, 0.64, 0.6 ],
       [0.3 , 0.73, 0.95, 0.43, 0.78],
       [0.06, 0.84, 0.19, 0.4 , 0.3 ],
       [0.08, 0.9 , 0.37, 0.53, 0.49],
       [0.13, 0.21, 0.08, 0.51, 0.26]])
```